# How to Build/Debug (full) LibTorch Sources on Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libtorch

The link below is an excellent description of how to download the prebuilt libtorch windows binaries and integrate them into Visual Studio.

https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-a-c-project-in-visual-studio-2019-with-libtorch-1-6-ad8a0e49e82c

I downloaded both the Debug and Release distributions for pytorch 1.8.1. I was surprised to see many duplicated directories/files in the two expanded zip files. The zip files both include the headers and *some* source. I was tempted to merge the two hierarchies, just keeping separate bin and lib folders, but some of the header files were not identical.

During the compile of my example project, I ran into a compiler error, that I fixed per the “SBW” comment line below.

```
template<bool Condition, class ThenCallback>
decltype(auto) if_constexpr(ThenCallback&& thenCallback) {
#if defined(__cpp_if_constexpr)
  // If we have C++17, just use it's "if constexpr" feature instead of wrapping it.
  // This will give us better error messages.
  if constexpr(Condition) {
    if constexpr (detail::function_takes_identity_argument<ThenCallback>::value) {
      // SBW 2021.05.12 Disambiguate std.
      // https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/53490/files/2ef3c80214c798afdf165d677fc04025b28166d7
      // return std::forward<ThenCallback>(thenCallback)(detail::_identity());
      return ::std::forward<ThenCallback>(thenCallback)(detail::_identity());
    } else {
      // return std::forward<ThenCallback>(thenCallback)();
      return ::std::forward<ThenCallback>(thenCallback)();
    }
  }
#else
  // C++14 implementation of if constexpr
  return if_constexpr<Condition>(std::forward<ThenCallback>(thenCallback), [] (auto) {});
#endif
}
```

Debugging an example project is an excellent way to learn about a new library, so one of the first things I did for my Debug build was to add copying of the .pdb files to the Post-Build step described in the link above.

My current project involves integrating libtorch models and optimizers with existing home-grown deep learning code. We had started this work a couple years ago with TensorFlow, but it stalled when we discovered the TF c++ api doesn’t support model training.

We have a custom optimizer that requires the calculation of the Jacobian during the training phase, which is not natively supported by libtorch, so I needed to learn about the autograd library. While debugging, I quickly found myself in a stack without accompanying source code – the Windows binaries downloads only include a subset of the source.

How do I get a full set of sources?

Answer (score 0):

After more investigation, I found the following answer, but I’m still hopeful there will be a vcpkg port per https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/17199

I did a .git of the source and then pointed VS towards the new folder when the debugger couldn’t find the source files. This almost worked, but I still found some of the functions were missing. Some of the autograd code is automatically generated via the python install. (This may be why the debug and release branches have slightly different files.)

Next I followed the build directions here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#from-source

For me, this resulted in the following steps:

** Get the PyTorch Source **

I pulled the full source from github, after having identified the 1.8.1 branch on the Releases page as Commid ID/SHA “56b43f4”:

> git clone https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch.git
> cd pytorch
> git checkout 56b43f4

** Anaconda **

Download/install (Python 3.8): Anaconda3-2021.05-Windows-x86_64.exe
Install for: Just Me
Advanced: Register Anaconda3 as my default Python 3.8

** Environment **

USE_CUDA=0

** Install Dependencies **

PS > conda install astunparse numpy ninja pyyaml mkl mkl-include setuptools cmake cffi typing_extensions future six requests dataclasses

** Install MKL/OpenMP **

These directions weren’t immediately clear to me. My machine already had mkl and opemmp in various places including the Anaconda distribution. I tried setting environment variables to these locations, but setup.py didn’t find libraries. Here’s what finally worked.

Download Intel oneAPI: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/base-toolkit/download.html?operatingsystem=window&distributions=webdownload&options=offline

Run: w_BaseKit_p_2021.2.0.2871_offline.exe
Choose both MKL and the Compiler (for OpenMP)

** Setup **

The instructions say to run “python setup.py install”, but the debug build failed due to a missing python38_d.lib.
I found this link that suggests a different command to build libtorch: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/17489

```
PS > $env:DEBUG=1
PS > $env:CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\latest\include"
PS > $env:LIB="C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\latest\lib\intel64"
PS > python tools\build_libtorch.py
```

This did the trick and I was finally able to debug with the full source. I’ve since learned that the many of the missing sources are built specifically to support the chosen backend.